# UTC date in string format send from JavaScript client to .NET is getting converted into DateTime

Tags: javascript, c#, date, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I am working with a client application written in JavaScript which sends data to ASP.NET web api end point (server).

I am asking user to select a date & time. I convert the that date into UTC datetime as `string` using .`toUTCString().`

I send this information to .NET application, which expects the value to be of `DateTime` type.

The value I am sending = `Thu, 31 Dec 2015 03:30:00 GMT`

value I receive on .net side = `{12/30/2015 10:30:00 PM}`

I understand the value is getting converted. My question is: How can I convert the date to UTC on the server side. My assumption is there is no implicit `timezone offset` attached to a `DateTime` object. If I run ToUniversalTime() on it when I'm running the code in Greenwich, then I get the same time. If I do it while I live in Vancouver, then I get an offset DateTime object of -8 hours.

So I a client coming from different location and I convert that time into UTC by using `.ToUniversalTime()`, the conversion will be wrong. How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: I personally prefer dealing with `DateTimeOffset`s server-side. That way it doesn't matter what time zone the client uses, as long as I can figure out what it is.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Correct me if I am wrong. But there is no implicit timezone attached to a `DateTime` object. If I run ToUniversalTime() on it when I'm running the code in Greenwich, then I get the same time. If I do it while I live in Vancouver, then I get an offset DateTime object of -8 hours. So how do I deal with `DateTimeOffset` at server side?

Comment: That's right. That's exactly why I prefer using `DateTimeOffset`s instead of `DateTime` objects. I'd suggest having some way to identify what time zone the current user is in, and use custom HtmlHelper extensions, Json Serializers, and Model Binders to always automatically convert DateTimeOffsets to and from the user's local time. This conversion should only ever happen at the fringes of your application (view code, and global model binders and serializers), so everything from the controller inward only deals with DateTimeOffsets.

Answer (score 0):

If a user selects date and time I assume it's not current and is relative to the user. In this case yes, you would want to convert to UTC if you want to further analyze data or present it to another user in another timezone. If you don't convert it to UTC, you would receive relative date/time and would need another data that indicates timezone. But even in that case, there is no point other than security measures to compute on the server something that could be easily computed on the client.